# Resizing UITableViewCell height

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, row-height

I'm having an extremely difficult time resizing the `.rowHeight` of the cells in my `.toDoListTable`. The strings received from a `UITextfield` are being cut-off at the end of each row. **I did not add a label when setting up a prototype cell since my strings are appended from a** `UITextField`. My code is as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


        toDoListTable.estimatedRowHeight = 45.0

        toDoListTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension


    }

}
```

Yet, I am still getting my text cut-off. Any suggestions? Also, is my code in the right spot?

I'm looking to have my content inside adapt to the amount of text provided from the `UITextField`.

EDIT: Solved problem by adding `cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0`.

Comment: Remove both line and Try this `self.toDoListTable.rowHeight = 45`

Comment: I tried, it didn't do anything for me. What I'm trying to do is instead of having the content get cut-off at the end of the line, is have in drop down to the next line. I want my cells to resize depending on the content inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I'm late but I wanted to correctly answer my own question.

I simply added: `cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0` to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function to allow for multiple lines of unrestricted text.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to set the height for the rows:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat
    {
         return 50 //your height
    }
```

**Documentation:**

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: Instead of setting a permanent size for the table rows, is there a way to change them depending on the content inside? For instance, if it's too long to display on one line, it will drop down to the next line.

Comment: I guess the best way is tha same way you're populating the tableview (with an array). for example: You return on the base of myDataArray[indexPath.Row].someValue.length, you do it with if statments: if .length > 30 return someValue, else returnSomethingElse, or You just return (myDataArray[indexPath.Row].someValue.length * multiplier)

Answer (score 3):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{
    return 30 // height you want to set.
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I want to resize them according to the content inside the UITextField. If there is too much content, instead of cutting it off at the end of the row, I want it to drop down to the next line and resize the table cell.